# How do I substract values from product table and order table?

Tags: php, sql

orders table

[image]

products table

[image]

The pictures are order and product table. I am trying to change my stock quantity of products where admin confirm the order of the customer and the product quantity will change according to the quantity added from the order table.

What I have tried:

I tried the code as below but there are no changes. Nothing works.

```
function upOrder(){
global $db;
    $uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $oid = intval($_GET['oid']);
    $pid = intval($_GET['pid']);
    $status = $_POST['status'];

            $sql=mysqli_query($db,"update orders set payment_status='$status', confirmDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where id='$oid'");

            if($status == 'Completed'){

            $result =mysqli_query($db,"SELECT productQty FROM products WHERE id = '$pid'");
            $query =mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '$oid' AND user_id = '$uid' AND product_id = '$pid'");

            $productRow = $result->fetch_assoc();
            $orderRow = $query->fetch_assoc();

            $newqty = $productRow['productQty'] - $orderRow['quantity'];
            $wow =mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE products SET productQty = '$newqty' WHERE id = '$pid'");

            if($wow){

                echo "alert('Order updated sucessfully...');";

            }else{

                echo "alert('Failed!');";

            }
            }
```

}

Comment: is the value for the $newqty variable correct before you update it? Also for the $pid, did you check if it's really existing in the products(id) table?

Comment: @Ronniel yeah the $newqty variable is correct. As for the $pid, i declared GET id method for the products table which is id. I am expecting the Hoodie Flex will decrease by the quantity of the orders which is 1.

Comment: I don't think I support the two individual SELECT queries before UPDATE'ing.  These 3 trips to the database should probably done in 1 trip.  Your queries are unstable/insecure because you are not using prepared statements to prevent injection attacks.

Comment: @mickmackusa yeah I there was some great guy ask me to use update join on the update part. Thanks for your advice btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code in my local server creating a database, but setting some variables

```
$uid = 41;
$oid = 165;
$pid = 38;
$status = 'Completed';
```

and the code is working just fine, so I've tried some other values to reproduce your error, so changing the uid:

```
$uid = 411;
$oid = 165;
$pid = 38;
$status = 'Completed';
```

The order is updated but the product doesn't.

This is because in the line

```
$query =mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '$oid' AND user_id = '$uid' AND product_id = '$pid'");
```

You are filtering the order by user_id, but the order may not have been created from the registered user.

You can verify this adding the following dump in your function:

```
var_dump(
    "product:".$productRow['productQty'], 
    "order:".$orderRow['quantity'], 
    "result:".($productRow['productQty'] - $orderRow['quantity'])
);
```

You expect to receive

```
string 'product:20' (length=10)
string 'order:1' (length=7)
string 'result:19' (length=9)
```

but you will receive:

```
string 'product:20' (length=10)
string 'order:' (length=6)
string 'result:20' (length=9)
```

Therefore, you must remove the user_id filter to allow the registered user to update the quantity in the product table

But if the user_id isn't the order's creator and correspond to the last modifier user, you must update the user_id value in the same statement line when you update the status and confirmation date

Hope this clears your doubts and solves your problem

Comment: Please do not advise users to perform unstable/unsafe query practices.  Always show how to use prepared statements with bound parameters.  (I am not picking on you -- it's just a coincidence)

Comment: Well, I'm trying to show Amirul Imran how to investigate the error. 
I'm not trying to encorage him to do it or not. Just resolving his doubt.
What a coincidence jeje

Comment: @CristianRichard your solution is very clear and understandable but I tried as you told where I tried  $sql=mysqli_query($db,"update orders set user_id ='$uid', payment_status='$status', confirmDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP where id='$oid'"); but I need to login to the admin first. So, this will make the user_id=0 in the database. Can you show me how its done?

Comment: So, the user_id is for the creator of the order or the modifier?
I think you are telling that it's for the creator, so the solution will be removing the user_id filter in the select statement for the order table to get the quantity field regardless the order was created for the logged user or not....  

$query =mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM orders WHERE id = '$oid' AND  product_id = '$pid'");

Comment: @CristianRichard I tried the select and I notice that the $pid is not working because it receive value of 0 when I dumping the sql as you told.

These are my new solution but it seems I got the 'Failed' alert for the new query:

$wow = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE p SET p.productQty = p.productQty - o.quantity FROM products p INNER JOIN orders o ON p.id = o.product_id
                    WHERE o.id = $oid
                    AND o.product_id = $pid");

Comment: @CristianRichard thanks bruh it works! i used the UPDATE JOIN query for the solution

$result = mysqli_query($db,"UPDATE products JOIN orders ON products.id = orders.product_id SET products.productQty = products.productQty - orders.quantity WHERE orders.product_id = products.id");

I noticed that the $pid is invalid because it is for the GET method for the user but not the admin. Therefore, i tried the above query for the solution